# Как объединить 2 функции в 1?

Tags: c#

```
    string Encrypt() //string to binary
        {
            var encrypt = textBox4.Text;

            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++)
            {
                binary.Append(Convert.ToString(encrypt[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }

            return binary.ToString();           
        }
    string papanya()
        {
            var encrypt = textBox3.Text;

            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++)
            {
                binary.Append(Convert.ToString(encrypt[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }

            return binary.ToString();
        }
```

Как вы можете заметить, они отличаются 1 строчкой. Можно ли как-нибудь сократить? Слишком много места занимает.

Comment: добавить параметр: `string Encrypt(string encrypt) {`, внутри функции убрать обращение к текстбоксам, а сделать его там где вызываете: `Encrypt(textBox3.Text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string Encrypt() //string to binary
{
    return Encrypt(textBox4.Text) ;         
}

string papanya()
{
    return Encrypt(textBox3.Text) ;           
}


string Encrypt(string text) //string to binary
{
    var binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        binary.Append(Convert.ToString(text[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    return binary.ToString();           
}
```

Comment: локальная переменная `encrypt` лишняя, вместо нее можно подставить параметр `text`, а переменную убрать

Comment: @trollingchar да и бог с ней

Comment: а как же идеальная чистота кода? :)

Comment: @trollingchar хорошо хорошо, уговорили )